# What happened to the greatsword Dawn?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

> The finest knight I ever saw was Ser Arthur Dayne, who fought with a blade called Dawn, forged from the heart of a fallen star. They called him the Sword of the Morning.

Was there any mention of what happened to Dawn, the greatsword wielded by Ser Arthur Dayne, The Sword of the Morning, after he was defeated by Lord Eddard Stark?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

House Dayne's ancestral greatsword Dawn was returned to them. After Ser Arthur Dayne was slain by Eddard Stark and/or Howland Reed, Eddard took the greatsword back to Arthur's sister the Lady Ashara.

> They whispered of Ser Arthur Dayne, the Sword of the Morning,
> deadliest of the seven knights of Aerys's Kingsguard, and how their
> young lord had slain him in single combat. And they told how afterward
> Ned had carried Ser Arthur's sword back to the beautiful young sister
> who awaited him in a castle called Starfall on the shores of the
> Summer Sea.
>
> **A Game of Thrones - Chapter 6 (Catelyn)**

That is the last we hear of Dawn in the books. But in [a web chat](http://web.archive.org/web/20060426235948/http://www.dromen-demonen.nl/luitingh_htdocs/transmartin.html), George R R Martin hinted that Dawn is still awaiting someone worthy enough for the title of Sword of the Morning to claim it. Most likely it is still housed in Starfall, House Dayne's seat of power.

> [Ran] Just to repeat frank's earlier question, in case it was missed:
> How does one earn the title Sword of the Morning?
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> [+GeorgeRRMartin] to ran sword of the morning is the title assumed by
> certain men of house dayne who are prooved worthy of wielding Dawn

Comment: Thanks! Don't know how I missed that passage in my own search.

Comment: @TerryChia - I missed it too in my first pass. It's such a little bit in a very big series that never gets mentioned again.

Answer (score 4):

After the fight Eddard Stark rode to Starfell and delivered it to Arthur's sister, Ashara.  That is the last anyone hears about it.

Comment: Any quotes from the book to back this up? I can't seem to recall any mention of this.

Comment: I don't have my books with me but this site says it was mentioned in Clash of Kings or A Game of Thrones. [link](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Dawn)

Comment: See: http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Dawn. It has refs to the books

Comment: @Ash - But not to that particular event. I'm looking through my copy of book 1 and I'm having trouble finding the relevant passage.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't note that particular claim had no ref...

Answer (score 2):

One earns the title of Sword of the Morning by being an exceptional swordsman, not by being the next in line to inherit the seat of Starfall.  Arthur Dayne was given the the title and sword because he was not only the deadliest swordsman in the seven kingdoms, but in Starfall. Arthur was neither the firstborn son, nor the heir to Starfall.

Answer (score 2):

As System Down stated, Ned returned the sword to Starfall after he was done with whole Tower of Joy business.

> That cut deep. Ned would not speak of the mother, not so much as a
>   word, but a castle has no secrets, and Catelyn heard her maids
>   repeating tales they heard from the lips of her husband's soldiers.
>   They whispered of Ser Arthur Dayne, the Sword of the Morning,
>   deadliest of the seven knights of Aerys's Kingsguard, and of how their
>   young lord had slain him in single combat. **And they told how
>   afterward Ned had carried Ser Arthur's sword back to the beautiful
>   young sister who awaited him in a castle called Starfall on the shores
>   of the Summer Sea**. The Lady Ashara Dayne, tall and fair, with
>   haunting violet eyes. It had taken her a fortnight to marshal her
>   courage, but finally, in bed one night, Catelyn had asked her husband
>   the truth of it, asked him to his face.
> <sub>**AGOT - Catelyn II**</sub>

George already confirmed in 2002 that the Sword is still at Starfall, waiting for another *Sword of the Morning* to rise and claim her. By customs of House Dayne, only the most puissant warrior of the family can wield the sword and be referred to as *the Sword of the Morning*.

> Q: What happened to Ser Arthur Dayne's sword Dawn after Ned brought it
>   back to Ashara?
>
> A: **Dawn remains at Starfall, until another Sword of the Morning
>   shall arise**.
> <sub>**[So Spake Martin: VALYRIA-RELATED SUBJECTS (The Citadel)](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/Valyria_related_Subjects)**</sub>

and also:

> The same guy asked about the Daynes and the Sword of the Morning,
>   asking how that title is decided. **George said the Sword of the
>   Morning is always a member of House Dayne, someone who is deemed
>   worthy of wielding Dawn as decided within the House, that whoever it
>   is would have to earn the right to wield it**.
> <sub>**[So Spake Martin: US SIGNING TOUR (ALBUQUERQUE, NM) (The Citadel)](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/1395/)**</sub>