# Who's the next possible "Sword of the Morning"?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

The title **[Sword of the Morning](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Sword_of_the_Morning)** is conferred upon a *worthy* member of **[House Dayne](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Dayne)** <sup>**1**</sup>

- the most recent and notable one being Ser **[Arthur Dayne](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Arthur_Dayne)**.

The **Sword of the Morning** then also becomes the worthy wielder of **[Dawn](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Dawn)**

- the ancestral [greatsword](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Greatsword) of **House Dayne**.

Currently, the [whereabouts of Dawn are unknown](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35156/what-happened-to-the-greatsword-dawn). But it is assumed that the Sword is in **[Starfall](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Starfall)**, or in safe keeping at the hands of the Daynes elsewhere.

**Who is the most likely candidate for Sword of the Morning?**<sup>✪</sup>

The person must be:

- A great **[Knight](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Knight)**
- Of **House Dayne**
- "Worthy"

  - Let's say brave, honourable and skilled
- Not necessarily the Lord or heir

---

<sup>✪ This question has no canon answer at this point, but given the criteria, we can at least narrow the candidates down using canonically sourced attributes.



**1.** From an [interview with G.R.R.M](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/1395/).</sup>

> asked about the Daynes and the Sword of the Morning, asking how that title is decided. George said the Sword of the Morning is always a member of House Dayne, someone who is deemed worthy of wielding Dawn as decided within the House, that whoever it is would have to earn the right to wield it.

Comment: I cant remember, but isn't Dayne House in the southern fields?

Comment: There don't appear to be a great deal of options. "Ned" would seem the most likely, but then there is a certain symbolism that would be interesting if it was the darkstar ("night" (the darkstar, sword of the night) turning into "day" (sword of the morning)). 
Of course, the page you linked mentioned that the title merely remains dormant so long as noone worthy of it exists, and so perhaps the title will remain dormant throughout the books.

Comment: This is a rather frustrating question, I don't think we are in anyway able to narrow down candidates. The whole southern part of westeros gained attention late in the tale. But I'd bet on Edric too. I'm more of a fan of the R+L=J theory TBH

Answer (score 3):

The candidates which spring to my mind are:

- **[Edric "Ned" Dayne](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Edric_Dayne)**

  - A little bit young, but he's pretty much the same age as Jon Snow
  - Arya has met him and he seems quite brave and honourable
- **[Gerold "Darkstar" Dayne](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Darkstar)**

  - Seems untrustworthy

  > - Slashed **[Myrcella](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Myrcella_Baratheon)**'s face in an attempt to kill her after the [botched plan to crown Myrcella as Queen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Arianne#A_Feast_for_Crows).

  - Calls himself "The Sword of the Night"

> - **[Jon Snow](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jon_Snow)**
>
>   - [Rumoured](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jon_Snow/Theories#Ashara_Dayne) to be the son of Lady **[Ashara Dayne](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Ashara_Dayne)**
>     Already shown exceptional skill with a Valyrian Steel sword
>     <sup>**1**</sup>
>     and valour as well as integrity

---

<sup>**1.** I know Dawn isn't a Valyrian Steel blade - it is made from the "heart of a fallen star" - but is compared to VS.</sup>